# error {-5001 : 0xffffec75} while installing

Tags: windows-10, installation

I am trying to install a program, but I am getting

An error {-5001 : 0xffffec75} has occurred while running the setup. Please make sure you have finished any previous setup and closed other applications. If the error still occurs, please contact your vendor.

I am using windows 10 OS.

Can some one tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Reboot your machine and try again

Comment: Also see if this related article assists you:   https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/OpenEdge-Installation-fails-with-error-5001-0xffffec75#:~:text=An%20error%20(%2D5001%3A%200xffffec75,please%20contact%20your%20vendor%3A%20PSC.&text=Move%20the%20install%20medial%20to%20the%20Server%20where%20OpenEdge%20is%20being%20installed.

Comment: @Mokubai I have tried it.